# Nifi Unable to Connect to Local MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I have Mysql running locally on port 3306. Nifi is also set up and working. I have a simple flow between QueryDatabaseTable and SplitAvro as shown,[image]

I have a DBCPConnectionPool controller set up as well,
[image]

Database Connection URL: **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/formulae**

Database Driver Class Name: **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

Database Driver Location: **C:\Users\chetanyadav\Documents\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12\mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar**

Database Name - **formulae**

Table Name - **cell_lot**

I am trying to access all records in my table using QueryDatabaseTable,
[image]

But I get this error,

[image]

I am unable to connect to MySQL basically and fetch the data from the tables.

Full Stack Trace of Error:

```
2018-09-18 09:52:30,917 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.p.standard.QueryDatabaseTable QueryDatabaseTable[id=d5293f61-0165-1000-cd8d-fe9155176abd] Unable to execute SQL select query SELECT * FROM cell_lot due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/formulae
': org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/formulae
'
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/formulae
'
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:276)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable.onTrigger(QueryDatabaseTable.java:303)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/formulae
'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:273)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: make sure the path to the jar file is readable by NiFi, windows paths are tricky

Comment: Shouldn't it be readable by default? I even tried putting it in nifi/lib folder. Nothing seems to be working :(

Comment: mysteries of Windozzz hehehe, Try this driver class name com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Nope, even that doesn't work. Sigh. I hate windows

Comment: It's not working even on my ubuntu VM.

Comment: If you're running NiFi as `nifi` user, that user should have permissions to access the file. Either change the ownership of the jar to the user NiFi is running as or give `read` permissions to everyone.

Comment: Changed the ownership/modifications as well and still, the same error appears. I have been at this for hours and I can't understand why it won't do such a simple thing!

Comment: @ChetanYadav, please provide the error with full stack trace from the nifi log file. there could be the details of the error.

Comment: @daggett Added above in question. Please check.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to work fine on my Ubuntu VM now but I don't understand why the same controller settings on Windows causes it to spit out the above error!

Comment: Can you try changing 'localhost' to `127.0.0.1` in connection url. It could be a binding issue.

Comment: the original error `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` is quite common for jdbc driver loading.. try to put `jar` into `NIFI/lib` folder restart nifi and clean the parameter `Database Driver Location`

Comment: Neither localhost nor the local ip work. Also, tried putting it in Nifi/lib folder and still the same error. It makes no sense as it works smoothly on my ubuntu with the exact same thing :/

Comment: @ChetanYadav, The problem in loading driver, not in the host... Did you remove `Database Driver Location` property? Do you have the same error in logs (No suitable driver) when you put jar into `nifi/lib` and remove `Database Driver Location` property?

Comment: Yeah, even after removing it from the Database Driver Location, the problem persists, with the exact same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I was using MySQL-connector.jar, I changed the connector to MySQL-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar and it worked. I Think there is a compatibility issue with new versions of the JDBC driver.